# Java char output isn't consistent

Tags: java, unicode, character

First, I want to apologize for the vague wording of the question, I can't figure out how to phrase it. 
I'm making a simple encryption program that takes a phrase changes each letter and then prints it out.

```
public class discussionBoardTest{
    public static void encrypt(String password){
        char temp;
        for(int i = 0; i<password.length(); i++){
            temp = password.charAt(i);
             temp *= 3;
             System.out.print(temp);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        encrypt("Discussion Board");
    }
}
```

The problem is that on my computer the output is a series of  `?`. On a friend's computer, however, the output is `ÈÒæÆêææÒÞÜ@ÄÞÂäÈ`. I'm assuming it has something to do with Unicode or Ansi or something like that, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: (1) Keep in mind a JAVA `char` is a 16-bit value. And (2) printing arbitrary characters on a console is a notoriously tricky problem, you should search for questions about doing that (look for "printing Unicode characters").

Comment: In short it makes little sense to perform arithmetic on text. If you need a mapping, get out the [Unicode character chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/) and create one. Note, however, that text encryption usually treats both its input and output as bytes rather than text.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's computer supports printing those characters out.

For example, `D` is UTF code point 68. Multiply that by 3 and you get 204, or [`Ì`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00CC/index.htm).

Comment: So how do I get my computer to support those characters?

Comment: Where are you printing out the letters to? Is it a terminal? Your IDE's console (if so, which one)? Other?

Comment: `char` holds a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit, not ASCII. 3 * 68 = 204 = 0xCC. So as a `char` it would be the complete Unicode codepoint [U+00CC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00CC/index.htm)(Ì).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that tried to help. The problem was that I wasn't saving the .java files with UTF-8 encoding so it didn't recognize the characters.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you comment out //temp*=3; it will print out each letter individually. Other than that, I do not know what you are trying to convert the string into.

Comment: I'm trying to change each letter to something else. For example if `temp = a` and then `temp += 1` and then `system.out.print(temp)` the output would read `b` but for some reason with `*=` the output is always a `?`.

Comment: Try : 
    temp += i; or temp*= i;

Comment: OP want's to use temp *= 3 and the answer changes the encryption algorithm. `+= i` will be to large for long strings.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class CharChange
{
public static void encrypt(String s)
{
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        temp = s.charAt(i);
        temp += i;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    encrypt("Hi my name is Nisha");
}
}
```

This one will work!! Hope it helped.

Comment: OP want's to use `temp *= 3` this answer uses `temp += i` so it does not answer the question.

Comment: Well *=3 is too big of a multiplier. I'm showing op the efficient way to run his program. I tried it and it worked perfectly. No need for random downvoting.

Comment: `+= i` is to big for a long string and can be larger than `*= 3`. But in the end you have changed the encryption algorithm.